# How do I search my WordPress site pages with search box

Tags: wordpress, search-box

How I search my WordPress site pages with search box I placed in my site?
Currently I am using this code.

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl')?>/" style="margin-left: -43px;">
    <input type="text" name="" id="s" class="textbox" placeholder="Search" required/>
    <input id="btnSearch" type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php _e('Search'); ?>" />
</form>
```

I used name="s" but it not do search properly. I want that if user right page1 name search box take it to siteurl/page1 and so for page2 and remaining page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure, you want to do this ? Because it may lead user to `404` page coz generally user don't have any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    function redirect_search() {
        if (is_search() && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
            wp_redirect(home_url("/").urlencode($_GET['s']));
            exit();
        }
    }
    add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_search' );
```

Add above code in your `functions.php` file.

So now when you type something, it will redirect it to that page.

**NOTE**:If you type something related to the **published post**, it will redirect to that **POST** instead of what have you entered.

For **example** : If I type `hello` in search box, then it will redirect you to `hello world`(which is default post that comes during installation of wordpress).

This is what have for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="content" class="textbox <?php echo of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos') ?>">
 <?php _e('Search for:',''); ?> "<?php the_search_query(); ?>"

    <?php 

        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                $format = get_post_format();
                get_template_part( 'include/'.$format );

                if($format == '')
                get_template_part( 'include/standard' );

         endwhile; else:

         ?>

            <?php echo '<p><strong>' . __('There has been an error.', '') . '</strong></p>'; ?>
            <p> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"><?php _e('return to home page', ''); ?></a> <?php _e('use the search .', ''); ?></p>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div><!--no-results-->

    <?php endif; ?>

  <?php get_template_part('include/post'); ?>
```